# My validation doesn't work for textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

How to check if textarea is not empty and display this sentence in `span`: "you shoud fill textbox"?

```
<textarea class="form-control"id="txtarea" rows="4"></textarea>

<span id="textspan" style="color:red"></span>

<script>               
    var textspan = document.getElementById('textspan');

    if($("#txtarea").val().length < 1)
    {
        $("#textspan").html('you shoud fill text area');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use `var isEmpty = $.trim(textAreaValue).length`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't put your complete code and i can't see a structure to show you error, when this error must be shown?
But if you have a button and want to show this error if an empty text area submitted and remove error when user enter an input, so try this:

```
var textspan = document.getElementById('textspan');
$('#txtarea').bind('input propertychange', function() { 
    if($("#txtarea").val().trim().length > 0){
        $("#textspan").html('');
    }
});

$("#Button1").click(function(){
    if($("#txtarea").val().trim().length < 1){
        $("#textspan").html('you shoud fill text area');
    }
});
```

You can see that if user try to submit an empaty textarea, get the error and when add any character to textarea, the error disappear.

[**Check JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckpz5xhd/1/)

Comment: tnx alot,it works in one of my program but it doesnot work in another and the message become flashing.it became refresh.can u help me?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle and simulate your problem? It's impossible to help you with this few provided details.

Comment: {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x3410290>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x39a21d0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': }

Answer (score 1):

In `textarea`s, white-spaces are not trimmed, so

```
<textarea> </textarea>
```

Already has a `val()` which is a **string** of *length* 1 and *value*  (a space);

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4bb2h84n/

That being said, all you need to do is to trim the value:

```
if($('#txtarea').val().trim().length < 1) { /* logic here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seem OK. You just have to wrap it with function and call this function on event of validation, when user tries to submit.

```
function validation(){
    if($("#txtarea").val().length < 1)
    {
        $("#textspan").html('you shoud fill text area');
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working answer ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1p6kmhcn/3/)) :

```
var updateWarning = function() {
    var inputEmpty = $("#textarea").val().trim().length == 0;
    if (inputEmpty) {
        $("#textspan").html('you shoud fill text area');
    }
    else {
        $("#textspan").html('');
    }
}

$("#textarea").keyup(updateWarning);
updateWarning();
```

Note that there's a lot of form validation libraries out there to help you with this.